# True or False? If a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} k^pa_k$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

True or False? If a series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges by either the ratio or root test, and if p > 0
is any constant, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} k^pa_k$$ converges by the same test.

My instinct is that this is true, but I am unsure as to how to go about proving it.

Comment: What if $a_k=\frac1{2^k}$ and $k=2$?

Comment: What is $k$? What is $n$? Shouldn't $k$ be $n$?

Comment: @ClementC. obviously a typo

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, but I also cannot (honestly) parse the part of the question saying " then k=1 ak." (and your comment -- $p=2$, right? :)

Comment: @GregoryGrant Please fix your "obvious" typo - it's not obvious what you meant to say.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: (1) What is $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(k+1)^p}{k^p}$? (2) What is $\lim_{k\to\infty} (k^p)^{1/k}$?

Comment: I can't read that part, it is not typeset in a way I can understand.

Comment: Apologies, I have cleared up the confusion. I had accidentally duplicated two parts of the question.

Comment: I am assuming we are using the simple version of the Ratio Test.If you are using the $\limsup$ version, some small changes will have to be made. We are told that $\lim\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|\lt1$. We want to show that $\lim\left|\frac{(k+1)^pa_{k+1}}{k^pa_k}\right|\lt 1$. Since $\lim \frac{(k+1)^p}{k^p}=1$, what we want to show follows.  Root Test is similar.